# Ubuntu Slack - how to copy/paste/save/export Slack messages?

Tags: slack

Is there a good way to copy/paste/save/export Slack chat messages with the Ubuntu Slack version?

Ref. this page https://slack.com/help/articles/201658943-Export-your-workspace-data#business+-plan-1 the company I work for has the **Business+ Plan**, but when I choose my organization's name at the top left, there is no `Settings & administration` option as described so these instructions don't help much.

To clarify, I'm not using Slack in a browser, I'm using the Ubuntu local install version available here https://slack.com/downloads/linux (I choose the `Download .DEB app` link)

I can copy/paste the text into a text document which works at a bare minimum but does not preserve formatting which I would like to retain in some cases.

Also I tried copy/pasting into LibreOffice Writer but it pastes in as unformatted text.

I've looked through the menu options pretty thoroughly so I doubt I've missed some non-obvious option, but I doubt it.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://slack.com/help/articles/204897248-Guide-to-Slack-import-and-export-tools :

"Workspace Owners and Admins can export data from public channels. Data exports will include links to files, but not the files themselves.

"Under limited circumstances, Workspace Owners may contact Slack and apply to export content from all channels and conversations, including private channels and direct messages. We will reject applications unless Workspace Owners show in each instance (a) valid legal process, or (b) consent of members, or (c) a requirement or right under applicable laws in order to export data."